# How to pass an object between multiple classes? Java

Tags: java, reference

```
public class FooClass {
    BarClass bar = null;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;

    public FooClass(BarClass bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        bar.setFoo(this);
    }
}

public class BarClass {
    FooClass foo = null;

    public BarClass(){}

    public void setFoo(FooClass foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

elsewhere...

```
BarClass theBar = new BarClass();
FooClass theFoo = new FooClass(theBar);
theFoo.a //should be 0
theBar.foo.a = 234; //I change the variable through theBar. Imagine all the variables are private and there are getters/setters.

theFoo.a //should be 234  <-----
```

How can I pass an object to another class, make a change, and have that change appear in the original instance of the first object?

or

How can I make a cycle where one change to a class is reflected in the other class?

Comment: Did you try it? It is exactly the way you want it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's already exactly how objects work in Java. Your code already does what you want it to.

When you pass `theBar` to the `FooClass` constructor, that's passing the value of `theBar`, which is a *reference* to a `BarClass` object. (`theBar` itself is passed by value - if you wrote `foo = new FooClass();` in the `BarClass` constructor, that wouldn't change which object `theBar` referred to. Java is strictly pass-by-value, it's just that the values are often references.)

When you change the value within that object using `theBar.foo.a`, then looking at the value of `a` again using `theFoo.a` will see the updated value.

Basically, Java doesn't *copy* objects unless you really ask it to.